# Why is this text not aligning to the center for mobile?

Tags: html, css

Here is the body text. There are no other css or html commands indicating alignment.

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9t4afmx3/

Why is it aligning to the left for mobile?

```
<body>

<p align="center"><img src="Screen Shot 2016-05-04 at 12.40.50 PM.png" width="1280" height="434.6" usemap="#Map" align="center" border="0" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
 <area shape="rect" coords="56.7,340.1,344.8,434.6" href="ourteam" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="472.37,340.1,755.8,434.6" href="ourservices" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="944.7,340.1,1228.15,434.6" href="aboutchillcreatives" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="472.30,500,804,5150" href="ourservices" />
 </map>
 </p>


<div align="center">
<pre class="chillfont"><span class="chillfont">CHILL CREATIVES IS</span>

  <span class="chillfont">FORFRONT...</span><span class="BLACKWHITE">IN AN
  </span><span class="BLACKWHITE">UNEQUIVOCALLY
 </span><span class="BLACKWHITE">CHILL FASHION.</span>
 <a href="ourservices">
 <img src="Screen Shot 2016-05-03 at 5.12.26 PM.png"   width="1200" height="1000"/>
 </a>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could be because `<p align="center">` is HTML3.2 syntax that hasn't been valid since HTML4, which came around long before mobile browsers ever did...

Comment: cool...thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 2):

there is no `align` attribute in a div or a p element. this code is wrong:

```
<div align="center">
```

you can use

```
<div style="text-align:center">
```

for centering the text

Comment: Tried this:
<div  style="text-align:center">

Comment: May be you have some responsive css included that overwrites the align setting

Answer (score 1):

Try `style = "text-align: center"` instead.